# Asymmetric algorithms - need a particular approach

Tags: c#, algorithm, cryptography

I have a very specific case for cryptography and I am just not sure what algorithms I need to use to achieve a result I am looking for.

So, it is as follows.
I will distribute an encrypted string to my clients, they will have a password to decrypt it. But I don't want them being able to create such encrypted strings themselves.

So, I need some particular algorithm that would allow me, and only me to encrypt something, and anyone can decrypt it if they have a password. but NOT encrypt.

Comment: look into RSA for such an algorithm.

Comment: does all your clients have a same password to decrypt or is each one having their own specific password for decryption ?

Comment: @JanDvorak hm, isn't that the opposite? Anyone can encrypt with public key and only owner of private key can decrypt.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. yes the same password to decrypt, it is for software authentication.

Comment: @NewProger depends on which key is the public one. You can publish the decryption key and keep the encryption key private.

Comment: @JanDvorak, no, it wouldn't work. Private key includes public key, so we cannot use it that way. Plus it is not intended to be used like that (it is much shorter) and is not secure whew used backwards.

Comment: @NewProger that's weird. CAs all over the world are using RSA to sign their certificates. Someone must have already abused this if it's as insecure as you say.

Comment: Any asymetric encryption can do what you want RSA is only an example for one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use certificate based encryption? This is exactly the way HTTPS/SSL encryption works.

The server has a certificate with public and private keys. The private key is used to encrypt data. The certificate with just the public key is distributed to the clients and the public key is used to decrypt data.

Comment: That is so simple... why didn't I think of that before! That is exactly what we need :) Thank you.